# Log4Net Message log

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, message, log4net-configuration

I am trying to use log4net for my web service. the problem that I am facing is that, when I try to send multiple messages at the same time, it's only creating the log for the first message.

The log is working fine when we send only one message at a time and wait until the message has reached the listener. But when we shoot multiple messages at the same time (without waiting for the response at the listener), it's only logging the first message that I sent.

Here is my configuration. Can anyone please let me know what I am missing:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>

    <log4net>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="ArchiveRollingFileAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="LogRollingFileAppender" />

        </root>

        <appender name="LogRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
                <key value="Source" />
                <stringToMatch value="Log" />
            </filter>
            <threshold value="OFF"/>
            <!--<lockingModel type="dndn.ebl.framework.logging.FileLock" />-->
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
            <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
                <conversionPattern value="{LogFileName}"/>
            </file>
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
            <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level [%property{method}] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="ArchiveRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
                <key value="Source" />
                <stringToMatch value="Archive" />
            </filter>
            <threshold value="OFF"/>
            <!--<lockingModel type="dndn.ebl.framework.logging.FileLock" />-->
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
            <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
                <conversionPattern value="{ArchiveFileName}"/>
            </file>
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
            <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting your lock model to

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

Comment: when i am sending like about 10 messages at once, its creating separate log files for the first 5 and the 6'th file is created with the 6'th message's ID but its storing the log for all the remaining files. Can you please tell me why this is happening ???

Comment: I have no experience with `PatternString` in the `<file>`. I always use `<file value="c:\staticpath\goes.here" />`